# Display load time in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, timestamp, page-load-time

I want to display in the footer of my html page the time it takes to load(using javascript). But I noticed that the load time displayed on the page doesn't match the page load time shown in the browser.

Here is my javascript code:

```
(() => {
     const loadStart = new Date().getTime();

     window.addEventListener('load', () => {
         const timeStamp = document.querySelector('#timestamp');
         timeStamp.innerHTML += `Page load time: ${(new Date().getTime() - loadStart) / 1000} sec`;
     });
 })();
```

I connect the script in  of the page and use the id of css-selector to display time.

The best solution I see is to use the JavaScript API but it's deprecated. I would like to use a more modern approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
time.loadEventStart - time.navigationStart
```

from performance.timing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).